# React/React Native viewableItems destructuring question

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is React/React Native but the question I feel is related to JavaScript. Anyway, this is what I have:

```
onViewableItemsChanged={({ viewableItems }) => {
    if (viewableItems.length > 0) {
        setActiveIndex(viewableItems[0].index || 0)
    }
}}
```

Here, **viewableItems** is something that is destructured. We can access it because we are working with **onViewableItemsChanged**. But when I move this function elsewhere, such as:

```
onViewableItemsChanged={onFlatlistUpdate}
```

```
const onFlatlistUpdate = useCallback(({ viewableItems }) => {
    if (viewableItems.length > 0) {
        setActiveIndex(viewableItems[0].index || 0)
    }
}, [])
```

I dont get where **viewableItems** is from? I mean in the first example, it is destructured from the context of **onViewableItemsChanged**. However in the second example, it is completely independent, away from **onViewableItemsChanged** (of course we are using **useCallback** but it does not matter) so how come we have access to it?

**TL DR:** In the 2nd example (onFlatlistUpdate), where is **viewableItems** destructured from/how come we have access to **viewableItems**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both examples, you're passing a function to the `onViewableItemsChanged` prop. In the first case, you're creating an anonymous function inline, and that function reference is passed to `onViewableItemsChanged`. In your second case, you're creating a function with`useCallback()` which you're then passing to `onViewableItemsChanged` (the function returned by `useCallback()` will forward any of the arguments it's passed to the function you give it). Internally, the `FlatList` component with the `onViewableItemsChanged` prop will call that function and pass an object with `viewableItems`, such as `onViewableItemsChanged({viewableItems: ...})`. This allows you to destructure the object within the function you've passed to your `FlatList` component.

> I mean in the first example, it is destructured from the context of
> onViewableItemsChanged

`onViewableItemsChanged` doesn't really have a "context". `onViewableItemsChanged` is just a prop that you pass a function to. How that function is then called within `FlatList` determines the arguments of the function. That's handled by the internals of `FlatList` component which you don't need to worry much about. You can create that function independently, or create it inline, in both cases, you're passing a function reference to `onViewableItemsChanged` that can be called by `FlatList`.

Take the following example code using vanilla JS, as we pass a callback function to another function for it to be invoked. It doesn't matter if we define the function as standalone or inline, all the really matters is that we end up passing a function to `myFlatList`:

```js
const myFlatList = (onViewableItemsChanged) => {
  onViewableItemsChanged({viewableItems: [1, 2, 3]});
}

// Defining the callback function inline 
myFlatList(({viewableItems}) => {
  console.log("inline", viewableItems);
});

// Similar to your `useCallback()` definition
const callbackFn = ({viewableItems}) => {
  console.log("independent", viewableItems);
}
myFlatList(callbackFn);
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I am new to these things and I am not 100% sure I understand everything correctly. But the way I think of it is like this - viewableItems will only work once it is passed as a prop to onViewableItemsChanged, where it "clicks" and "matches" because onViewableItemsChanged does have the viewableItems property. Otherwise, if it is not "connected" to onViewableItemsChanged, it is useless. Is this an ok way to see it?

Comment: @5ecured Yes, `viewableItems` only makes sense if the function that it's being used in is passed to the `onViewableItemsChanged` prop, because internally, `FlatList` will call the `onViewableItemsChanged` and pass an object with the `viewableItems` property on it that can be destructured (as shown in the last snippet). Both of your examples are doing that, in the first one you've created a function that destructures the `viewableItems` property and that function is passed to `onViewableItemsChanged`.

Comment: In the second example, you've created a function that also destructures the `viewableItems`, and are passing that to the `onViewableItemsChanged` prop as well.